# Calculation in Sum Field in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which is returning me a sum group by mode of payment

```
select
RTRIM(shopNo) as Shop_Number,
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateTransaction, 103), '/', '') AS Todays_Date,
CodeModeDePaiement as Mode_Of_Payment,
SUM(convert(DOUBLE PRECISION,  Amount * 100 ) * 10) As Amount
from InvoiceSettlement
where  CodeModeDePaiement in 
(101,130,132,135,104,103,124,107,
136,117,131,410,106,122,109,102,105,112,133,999)
and   DateTransaction =  '2017/12/31' 
group by ShopNo,DateTransaction,CodeModeDePaiement
```

The output result is a below :

```
Shop_Number Todays_Date Mode_Of_Payment Amount
  2         31122017    102             18421610
  2         31122017    130             2332371390
  2         31122017    132             1082810
  2         31122017    106             66457640
  2         31122017    117             23925000
  2         31122017    133             5700000
  2         31122017    999             -490653940
  2         31122017    101             2404194870
```

I want the result to always display Sum Amount for Mode_of_Payment(101 + 999) as 101. I need the result as below :

```
Shop_Number Todays_Date Mode_Of_Payment Amount
  2         31122017    102             18421610
  2         31122017    130             2332371390
  2         31122017    132             1082810
  2         31122017    106             66457640
  2         31122017    117             23925000
  2         31122017    133             5700000
  2         31122017    101             1913540930
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic a bit more? Is it just PaymentMode 999 you want to add to 101? In that case you can use a case expression: `CASE WHEN CodeModeDePaiement = 999 THEN 101 ELSE CodeModeDePaiement END as Mode_Of_Payment`, and same in `group by`.

Comment: Small point, why do you alias `DateTransaction` as 'Todays_Date' when you are querying data from last year?

Comment: @PaulCampbell Actually the application is running the query on a daily basis , the fields name has been defined as such in the requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression to map 101 and 999 to the same thing:

```
SELECT
    RTRIM(shopNo) AS Shop_Number,
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateTransaction, 103), '/', '') AS Todays_Date,
    CASE WHEN CodeModeDePaiement IN (101, 999)
         THEN 101
         ELSE CodeModeDePaiement END as Mode_Of_Payment,
    SUM(CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION,  Amount * 100 ) * 10) AS Amount
FROM InvoiceSettlement
WHERE CodeModeDePaiement IN (101, 130, 132, 135, 104, 103, 124, 107, 136, 117,
    131, 410, 106, 122, 109, 102, 105, 112, 133, 999) AND
    DateTransaction = '2017/12/31' 
GROUP BY
    ShopNo,
    DateTransaction,
    CASE WHEN CodeModeDePaiement IN (101, 999)
         THEN 101
         ELSE CodeModeDePaiement END;
```